# how to decrease size of drop item container in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to decrease the size of drop down container but I'm unable to do so I have written the following code but it's out of use If anyone knows the solution plese help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">             
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width: 40px">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this is what you were trying to do(min-width is assigned to dropdown , change that to resize the dropdown size, the set width)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">             
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="min-width: 40px">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: answer is edited, min-width:160px is a ready given in css, so it will be taken, change that then set the max-width if needed

Answer (score 0):

> Html

```
  <div class="container">             
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-width">
          <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

> CSS

```
.dropdown-width{
      min-width:40px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
enter code <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">             
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="max-width: 40px; min-width: 0">
      <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>here
```